# How to render unicode characters in LINQPad using emoji style (colorful)?

Tags: c#, emoji, linqpad

How to render unicode characters in LINQPad using emoji style (color) instead of character style (monochromatic)?

I tried the following code (with VARIATION SELECTOR-16 to force emoji style):

```
Console.WriteLine("\u26D4\uFE0F \u2714\uFE0F");
```

Or:

```
Util.RawHtml(new XElement("span", "\u26D4\uFE0F \u2714\uFE0F")).Dump();
```

However, it renders the output in text style (monochromatic).

Comment: You might be better off asking this directly at their forum: http://forum.linqpad.net/